# Flying to Frankfurt with a transit through Paris - is 90 minutes enough for a layover?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, cdg, short-connections

I have a flight booking from San Jose, USA to Frankfurt, Germany. The itinerary has a transit through Charles de Gaulle, Paris. Since this will be my first stop in the Schengen Region, will I have to go through Passport control at Paris?

My concern is that my flight has a transit time of 90 minutes at CDG. Will this be enough to go through whatever administrative steps are required?

EDIT: I'm an Indian citizen with a Long-Term residence visa for Germany.

Comment: Citizenship might play a role.

Comment: Yes, you should go through the Schengen entry check in Paris.

Comment: Added citizenship information. What I'm concerned about is if the layover time is sufficient.

Comment: What terminals are your flights from? Or, if you don't know, what are your flights?

Comment: Usually crossing the border in the morning (like many transatlantic flights) without specific trouble in CDG + exiting the airport takes more or less an hour so crossing the border and catching another flight shall be fine in 90 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is "probably yes but it's not guaranteed". While 90 minutes is plenty in most circumstances, immigration at CDG can be occasionally very crowded and extremely slow. Last time I went through there 90 minutes would not have been enough and there were no provision to accelerate passengers with tight connections.

If you miss he connection and if the inbound and outbound flight are on the same ticket, the airlines will get you there eventually without extra cost. That shouldn't be a big deal: there are more than a dozen non-stops from CDG to FRA and the airline should be able to get you on the next one.

If both flights are on separate tickets, than you carry the full risk of missing the connection and you may have to spend significant cash to re-book your flight.

Most US flight arrive around the same time (early to mid morning). Having a lot of large transatlantic planes coming in at all at once increases your risk of missing the connection, so looking at the arrival schedule at CDG can give you a hint how bad it might be.